# Android open image from internal storage with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to follow these instructions https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider for opening an image with Intent from internal folder.
My path image is '/data/data/com.saffru.colombo.cartellaclinica/files/imgs/IMG-20200422-WA0001.jpg'

In my Manifest I added the provider as follow

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.saffru.colombo.cartellaclinica.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

My provider_paths.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
 <files-path name="my_images" path="img/"/>
 <cache-path name="img" path="img" />
</paths>
```

In my Activity I've an Imageview where I show the Bitmap image and with a click a user can open this image, but it doesn't work. Here my code

```
        File file = new File(pathFile);

        File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "img");
        File newFile = new File(imagePath, file.getName());
        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ViewEsameActivity.this,
                "com.saffru.colombo.cartellaclinica.fileprovider", newFile);


        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        grantUriPermission("com.saffru.colombo.cartellaclinica" +
                ".fileprovider", contentUri,
                FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setDataAndType(contentUri,"image/*");
        intent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Once the Gallery application is opened I receive the error 'File format isn't supported or file are corrupted'

Comment: What is the value of contentUri.toString()?

Comment: You are messing around with imgs and img/img.

Comment: yep, the problem was the wrongs names, thank you so much